# Get return value of http onload function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

How can i get the response value from the http onload function? I know it's something with a Asynchronous call!

```
httpRequest.onload = function() {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        test(response);
        /*....*/ 
};

exports.test = function(){
  return response;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest for how to use this object.

Comment: Well, the thing with asynchronous calls is that you cannot. The callbacks return to nowhere!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the exact problem you're having and to make sure it's not a duplicate of [How to return the response from an ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572)